# What is a good cms that is postgres compatible, open source and either php or python based?

Tags: postgresql, content-management-system, python-2.7

- Php or python
- Use and connect to our existing postgres databases
- open source / or very low license fees
- Common features of cms, with admin tools to help manage / moderate community

  have a large member base on very basic site where members provide us contact info and info about their professional characteristics.  About to expand to build new community site (to migrate our member base to) where the users will be able to msg each other, post to forums, blog, share private group discussions, and members will be sent inivitations to earn compensation for their expertise. Profile pages, job postings, and video chat would be plus.

  Already have a team of admins savvy with web apps to help manage it but our developer resources are limited (3-4 programmers) and looking to save time in development as opposed to building our new site from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Drupal.  Drupal supports PostgreSQL and is written in PHP and is open source.

Comment: I have added drupal to short list, any other options? There seems be lot of small fractured communities or groups writing their own new cms but so many have halted development or too small community. Drupal and kotti cms/pyramid are all i got so far

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still interested, with Python and support PostgreSQL: Django-cms and Plone

[List of Contentmanagement systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems)